# Mapping netCDF file in the right location with different value and location files

Tags: qgis, gdal, netcdf

I'm looking to work with data from the Sentinel-3 Sat of ESA.
I downloaded data in a zip with multiple netCDF files.

I want to open the data in QGIS in order to visualise it.
I figure out that the ogvi.nc file that I need is not georeferenced. But I suppose that the coordinates are stored in the geo_coordinates.nc file, that contains 3 subdatasets (lon, lat and alt).

```
$ gdalinfo NETCDF:"ogvi.nc":OGVI


Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: ogvi.nc
Size is 4865, 4090
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#absolute_orbit_number=27343
  NC_GLOBAL#ac_subsampling_factor=64
  NC_GLOBAL#al_subsampling_factor=1
  NC_GLOBAL#comment= 
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=eosupport@copernicus.esa.int
  NC_GLOBAL#creation_time=2021-05-18T09:46:47Z
  NC_GLOBAL#history=  2021-05-18T09:46:47Z: PUGCoreProcessor /data/ipf-s3/workdir151/630204639/JobOrder.630204639.xml
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=LN1
  NC_GLOBAL#netCDF_version=4.2 of Mar 13 2018 10:14:33 $
  NC_GLOBAL#product_name=S3A_OL_2_LFR____20210518T074422_20210518T074722_20210518T094647_0179_072_035_1980_LN1_O_NR_002.SEN3
  NC_GLOBAL#references=S3IPF PDS 004.2 - i2r3 - Product Data Format Specification - OLCI Level 2 Land, S3IPF PDS 002 - i1r7 - Product Data Format Specification - Product Structures, S3IPF DPM 008 - i2r1 - Detailed Processing Model - OLCI Level 2
  NC_GLOBAL#resolution=[ 270 294 ]
  NC_GLOBAL#source=IPF-OL-2 06.14
  NC_GLOBAL#start_time=2021-05-18T07:44:22.002275Z
  NC_GLOBAL#stop_time=2021-05-18T07:47:21.923237Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=OLCI Level 2 LAND Product, Global Vegetation Index Data Set
  OGVI#add_offset=0
  OGVI#long_name=OLCI Global Vegetation Index
  OGVI#scale_factor=0.0039370079
  OGVI#_FillValue=255
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4090.0)
Upper Right ( 4865.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4865.0, 4090.0)
Center      ( 2432.5, 2045.0)
Band 1 Block=4865x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=255
  Offset: 0,   Scale:0.00393700785934925
  Metadata:
    add_offset=0
    long_name=OLCI Global Vegetation Index
    NETCDF_VARNAME=OGVI
    scale_factor=0.0039370079
    _FillValue=255
```

```
$ gdalinfo geo_coordinates.nc   

Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: geo_coordinates.nc
Size is 512, 512
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#absolute_orbit_number=27343
  NC_GLOBAL#ac_subsampling_factor=64
  NC_GLOBAL#al_subsampling_factor=1
  NC_GLOBAL#comment= 
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=eosupport@copernicus.esa.int
  NC_GLOBAL#creation_time=2021-05-18T09:46:47Z
  NC_GLOBAL#history=  2021-05-18T09:46:47Z: PUGCoreProcessor /data/ipf-s3/workdir151/630204639/JobOrder.630204639.xml
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=LN1
  NC_GLOBAL#netCDF_version=4.2 of Mar 13 2018 10:14:33 $
  NC_GLOBAL#product_name=S3A_OL_2_LFR____20210518T074422_20210518T074722_20210518T094647_0179_072_035_1980_LN1_O_NR_002.SEN3
  NC_GLOBAL#references=S3IPF PDS 004.2 - i2r3 - Product Data Format Specification - OLCI Level 2 Land, S3IPF PDS 002 - i1r7 - Product Data Format Specification - Product Structures, S3IPF DPM 008 - i2r1 - Detailed Processing Model - OLCI Level 2
  NC_GLOBAL#resolution=[ 270 294 ]
  NC_GLOBAL#source=IPF-OL-2 06.14
  NC_GLOBAL#start_time=2021-05-18T07:44:22.002275Z
  NC_GLOBAL#stop_time=2021-05-18T07:47:21.923237Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=OLCI Level 2 LAND Product, Geo Coordinates Data Set
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"geo_coordinates.nc":altitude
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[4090x4865] altitude (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"geo_coordinates.nc":latitude
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[4090x4865] latitude (32-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"geo_coordinates.nc":longitude
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[4090x4865] longitude (32-bit integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Here are the gdalinfo about latitude :

```
$ gdalinfo NETCDF:"geo_coordinates.nc":latitude

Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: geo_coordinates.nc
Size is 4865, 4090
Metadata:
  latitude#long_name=DEM corrected latitude
  latitude#scale_factor=1e-06
  latitude#standard_name=latitude
  latitude#units=degrees_north
  latitude#valid_max=90000000
  latitude#valid_min=-90000000
  latitude#_FillValue=-2147483648
  NC_GLOBAL#absolute_orbit_number=27343
  NC_GLOBAL#ac_subsampling_factor=64
  NC_GLOBAL#al_subsampling_factor=1
  NC_GLOBAL#comment= 
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=eosupport@copernicus.esa.int
  NC_GLOBAL#creation_time=2021-05-18T09:46:47Z
  NC_GLOBAL#history=  2021-05-18T09:46:47Z: PUGCoreProcessor /data/ipf-s3/workdir151/630204639/JobOrder.630204639.xml
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=LN1
  NC_GLOBAL#netCDF_version=4.2 of Mar 13 2018 10:14:33 $
  NC_GLOBAL#product_name=S3A_OL_2_LFR____20210518T074422_20210518T074722_20210518T094647_0179_072_035_1980_LN1_O_NR_002.SEN3
  NC_GLOBAL#references=S3IPF PDS 004.2 - i2r3 - Product Data Format Specification - OLCI Level 2 Land, S3IPF PDS 002 - i1r7 - Product Data Format Specification - Product Structures, S3IPF DPM 008 - i2r1 - Detailed Processing Model - OLCI Level 2
  NC_GLOBAL#resolution=[ 270 294 ]
  NC_GLOBAL#source=IPF-OL-2 06.14
  NC_GLOBAL#start_time=2021-05-18T07:44:22.002275Z
  NC_GLOBAL#stop_time=2021-05-18T07:47:21.923237Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=OLCI Level 2 LAND Product, Geo Coordinates Data Set
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4090.0)
Upper Right ( 4865.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4865.0, 4090.0)
Center      ( 2432.5, 2045.0)
Band 1 Block=4865x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-2147483648
  Unit Type: degrees_north
  Offset: 0,   Scale:1e-06
  Metadata:
    long_name=DEM corrected latitude
    NETCDF_VARNAME=latitude
    scale_factor=1e-06
    standard_name=latitude
    units=degrees_north
    valid_max=90000000
    valid_min=-90000000
    _FillValue=-2147483648
```

I would like to "merge" those two files in order to open the ogvi data in the right location. I looked for other related questions on this forum but the problem was not exactly the same and I can't understand how to adapt the answer for my problem ([Mapping a NetCDF in QGIS in the correct location on Earth](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379701/mapping-a-netcdf-in-qgis-in-the-correct-location-on-earth)).